# Have views.py in Django Project directory

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

As a first project I am trying to make a website with Django. In this, I have some apps which have their own templates in their templates directory.

For some generic pages such as "About Us" "Home" etc, I was wondering if I create a views.py in the project's directory, where settings.py wsgi.py urls.py are also present. And also have templates for the pages taken from the same project directory.

Is it advisable to do that? Would there be any security issues?

I am sorry if my vocabulary is not clear. I don't know how to really call this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create simple website with Django, throwing the views.py inside your app's home directory should be fine.

A simple project structure may look as follows:

```
Project Home Directory
+-- App Home Directory
|   +-- views.py
|   +-- settings.py
|   +-- urls.py
|   +-- wsgi.py
|   +-- templates
|       +-- index.html
|   +-- static
|       +-- [css/javascript files]
+-- manage.py
+-- db.sqlite3
```

Security issues will mostly depend on how you configure your server. Placing views.py in your app's home directory should not in itself be a security issue.